# dynamically setting artifact path/folder structure on gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following `gitlab-ci.yml` file that reads the `package.json` using the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) processor to dynamically set the variable name of the artifact folder, something along the lines of

```
image: node:latest

stages:
 - build

before_script:
    ## steps ignored for purpose of question
    - export NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER=$(cat package.json | jq -r .name)"_"$(cat package.json | jq -r .version)".zip"
    - echo $NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER ##prints the expected name here eg. myApp_1.0.0.zip

prod_build:
  stage: build
  script:
   - echo $NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER ##prints the expected name here eg. myApp_1.0.0.zip
   - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/$NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER ## this does not work
    expire_in: 2 hrs
```

The issue here is `- dist/$NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER` does not work, not sure if am missing something here.

**EDIT**

Upon hard coding the expected path such as the following, it works fine, which would mean that the folder name is valid and that the artifact is indeed identified appropriately, but does NOT work when coming from `$NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER`

```
 artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/myApp_1.0.0.zip ##hardcoding the expected works just fine
    expire_in: 2 hrs
```

Comment: Why do you want it to work like that?

Comment: **for the same reasons as anyone not wanting to hard code the folder name generated dynamically and or subjected to change**. Not sure if you read the entire question.
tl-dr- I capture the name and version of the project from package.json to generate the zipped artifact folder as part of `yarn build` and would want gitlab to identify the said artifact for deployment

Comment: @Jaya were you able to make this work somehow? Or do I really have to hardcode my .zip in build stage?? omg

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did not. Atleast not at that time of posting the question (almost 3 yrs back). Hoping things have changed and gitlab has incorporated the feature in it. Good luck @trainoasis.

Answer (score 5):

While @Jakub Kania was not that wrong with it's summary

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49659852/529977
> That is no variables set in your script part of the job can be used.

and I have to redict my own comment beneath @Matt Bracewell's post

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/66707954/529977
> I don't see this will help anything because it addresses artifacts:name but not artifacts:paths . paths is still not dynamically usable as you can see in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html

~~**the undocumented part says:**__~~

**you can use any variable in artifacts:path that is available at job level**

i.e.

```
  prod_build:
+   variables:
+      NAME_OF_ARTIFACT: "myApp_*.zip"
    stage: build
    script:
     - echo $NAME_OF_ARTIFACT
     - yarn run build
    artifacts:
      paths:
      - dist/$NAME_OF_ARTIFACT
      expire_in: 2 hrs
```

That's indeed consequent to what is asked in [Artifacts Filename Cannot Be Set with Dynamic Variables](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1664) even they don't ask for `paths` but `names`

```
generate for myself:
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - |
      cat > build/artifact1$$.txt <<EOF
      Hello World! ${CI_PROJECT_ID} ${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
      EOF
    - export MY_VAR_FILE_NAME=artifact1$$
    - echo "MY_VAR_FILE_NAME=${MY_VAR_FILE_NAME}" >> generate.env
    - |
      cat > build/artifact2$$.txt <<EOF
      The end is near! ${CI_PROJECT_ID} ${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
      EOF
    - export MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME=artifact2$$
    - echo "MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME=${MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME}" >> generate.env
    - |
      cat > build/ci${CI_PIPELINE_IID}.txt <<EOF
      Happy to hear you! ${CI_PROJECT_ID} ${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
      EOF
  artifacts:
    reports:
      # using the https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv 
      # does NOT do the trick to fill a job variable before artifact:paths is evaluated!
      dotenv: generate.env
    paths: 
      - build/ci${CI_PIPELINE_IID}.txt # WORKS!
      - build/$MY_VAR_FILE_NAME.txt    # doen't work
      - build/$MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME.txt   # doen't work
```

⚠️ unknown variables are expanded to empty and `build/$MY_VAR_FILE_NAME.txt` becomes `build/` i.e. all files in build folder are artifacts - mentioned in pipeline out `WARNING: build/.txt: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory`  resp. unexpected `build/: found 4 matching files and directories`

As a workaround - but yes, it's ugly -, you can do the trick either by using wildcards (but I assume you have good reasons to do not)

```
prod_build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/*.zip
```

OR splitting into two jobs

```
generate before save:
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - |
      cat > build/artifact1$$.txt <<EOF
      Hello World! ${CI_PROJECT_ID} ${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
      EOF
    - export MY_VAR_FILE_NAME=artifact1$$
    - echo "MY_VAR_FILE_NAME=${MY_VAR_FILE_NAME}" >> generate.env
    - |
      cat > build/artifact2$$.txt <<EOF
      The end is near! ${CI_PROJECT_ID} ${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
      EOF
    - export MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME=artifact2$$
    - echo "MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME=${MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME}" >> generate.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      # using the https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv trick to fill a job variable for downstream of successor job
      dotenv: generate.env
    paths: 
      - build/*.txt

save artifacts:
  ## this is your expected input:
  # variables:
  #   MY_VAR_FILE_NAME: #filled by dotenv
  #   MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME: #filled by dotenv
  needs:
    - generate before save
  script:
    - find build/
    - echo "expecting … "
    - echo "- $MY_VAR_FILE_NAME"
    - echo "- $MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME"
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - build/$MY_VAR_FILE_NAME.txt    # WORKS
      - build/$MY_VAR_FILE2_NAME.txt   # WORKS
```

i.e. in your case:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
 - build

pre_prod_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    ## steps ignored for purpose of question
    - export NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER=$(cat package.json | jq -r .name)"_"$(cat package.json | jq -r .version)".zip"
    - echo $NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER ##prints the expected name here eg. myApp_1.0.0.zip
    - echo "NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER=${NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER}" >> artifact_name.dotenv
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: artifact_name.dotenv

prod_build:
  stage: build
  ## this is your expected input:
  # variables:
  #   NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER: # set by pre_prod_build dotenv
  needs:
    - job: pre_prod_build
  script:
   - echo $NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER ##prints the expected name here eg. myApp_1.0.0.zip
   - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/$NAME_OF_ARTIFACT_FOLDER ## NOW IT WORKS
    expire_in: 2 hrs
```

Comment: A great thanks @childno͡.de ! Your workaround is perfect !

Comment: For the split jobs You actually don't need to provide empty variables, the variables are populated by dotenv regardless.

Comment: correct @gardar , just added it as like "the interface definition of prod_build", just updated it above, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Well, that is not possible currently. [Manual](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts-name) says as follows:

> The artifacts:name variable can make use of any of the predefined variables.

That is no variables set in your script part of the job can be used.

Comment: My question is about the artifacts path and not the name. am confused

Comment: @Jaya Oh, yeah you're right. Same thing goes, you can't use anything outside of predefined variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is an open issue at GitLab

[Artifacts Filename Cannot Be Set with Dynamic Variables](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1664)

I had a project variable defining the path to a zip file in a script which I reused at artifacts:paths level. The linked issue would have been more obvious had the artifacts:paths instance completely failed to get assigned but in my case it inherited a different value from that a mere two lines above in my job!

Comment: I don't see this will help anything because it addresses `artifacts:name` but not `artifacts:paths` . paths is still not dynamically usable as you can see in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html

Comment: @childno͡.de you're right!